# ! LaTeX Error: Command \textcurrency unavailable in encoding T1

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\title{Der Name Ihrer Arbeit}
\author{Ivan Arov}

\maketitle  
\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage                
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage

by road, are as short as possible."\cite{UIRR}

 this problem ~\cite{intermodal}:

 \cite{container repositioning}. This significantly decreases the level of efficiency of railways. This problem can be  solved 


 deployed on other services, would stand idle.  \cite{production systems}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{literature}


\end{document}
```

I am sorry for asking the same question, but I am using latex for 2-3 days now... I also have problems with citing - some of the sources are not included in the output file. I`ll be grateful if somene helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no `\textcurrency` in your example; anyway, the problem is solved by adding `\usepackage{textcomp}`. About the citations: did you run BibTeX after adding new ones?

Comment: Yes, I did. Could it be that there shouldnt be "space" between production systems?

Comment: Doesn't that error more sound like an encoding problem? Perhaps the bibliography contains chars not belonging to `ansinew`?

Comment: @daleif Possibly so.

Comment: @user59969 Oh, that's definitely a possibility: BibTeX doesn't like spaces in the citation keys.

Comment: @incollection{production systems,
  title={International combined transport production systems including long and heavy trains},
  booktitle={Developing infrastructure and operating models for intermodal transport (DIOMIS)},
  year={2007},
  publisher={International union of railways (UIC)}
}



@book{container repositioning,
  title={The geography of transport systems},
  author={Rodrigue, Jean-Paul and Comtois, Claude and Slack, Brian},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Routledge}
}

Comment: You were right. I had used "()" , when I deleted them, everything worked just fine. Thank You! Wish You everithyng nice!

Comment: @user59969 As your question is not really showing the problem you had, you might consider to update it with the culprit parts and to answer your own question (and accept the answer). If you think, this question will not help others in future, just delete it. One of this two approaches would close this issue. Thank you.

Comment: The main problem was fixed by the comman \usepackage{textcomp}.

Answer (score 7):

One reason why this error message occurs might be the wrong encoding.

Make sure that your files are encoded as UTF-8. If you're using a Linux system, you can execute `file whatever.tex` to get something like

```
whatever.tex: LaTeX document, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Then make sure you use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and not `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` or similar. (This was just what fixed the error message for me.)

Comment: How do I make sure my files are encoded as UTF-8 under Windows?