# how to add references (basic)

Tags: biblatex, citing, ref

This may seem an easy problem to you but for me I am struggling with it!.I need a little help with adding references in my report. I am able to compile and get a pdf doc but my problem is how to cite. I used \cite{ref1} but it does connect with the .bib file. I am getting [ref1] instead of [1].

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 %\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp]{biblatex}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=latinl]{biblatex}
 %\addbibresource{folder/references.bib}
 \begin{document}
my report here
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

% Here is the references.bib file in which I have the citation
%both the main file and bib file are saved in the same folder

```
@book{ref1,
isbn = {3-662-45239-1},
title = {Scanning Probe Microscopy},
language = {eng},
author = {VoigtlÃ¤nder, Bert},
publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
}
```

Comment: Should be in any decent LaTeX article book /article about bibliography. Maybe something like `\cite{ref1}` see a.o. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management but also the documetation of the biblatex packack

Comment: Maybe you find more information [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management).

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864. The symptoms suggest you did not run Biber, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. But your encoding settings should be checked. The `ä` in `Voigtländer` seems wrong. Nowadays most editors use UTF-8 instead of `latin1` (ISO 8859-1). If the encoding of your `.bib` file and your `.tex` as declared with `\usepackage[...]{inputenc}` coincide, there is no need for the `bibencoding` option.

Comment: You need a line `\addbibresource{references.bib}` to tell `biblatex` which file to look for.

Comment: Andrew Swann I did this   \addbibresource{references.bib} it did not give error but no pdf is produced

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Answer (score 2):

Your are close, but there are two errors

1. you need a line `\addbibresource{references.bib}` so `biblatex` finds the bib file
2. `latinl` is not a valid encoding, it should be `latin1`  (or switch to the default `utf8`)

Here is a minimal document

[image: Sample text]

[image: Sample bib]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=latin1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

My report here \cite{ref1}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with `references.bib`

```
@book{ref1,
  isbn =     {3-662-45239-1},
  title =    {Scanning Probe Microscopy},
  language =     {eng},
  author =   {Voigtländer, Bert},
  publisher =    {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew!. I did it but I had another error it is : \textcurrency unavailable in encoding T1

Comment: Did you also correct the name of the bibencoding?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper]{report}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 %\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp]{biblatex}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=latin1]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{references.bib}
 \begin{document}

Comment: You should double check the file encodings, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194083/15925

Comment: sorry, I did not apply your solutions properly. Now , I simply copied and pasted your code above and it works!. I have a doc with citation .I can see [1] there. However, the command \printbibliography gives an error ( Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Â¤ (U+A4)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation)

Comment: Good to hear.  You may well have to remove the auxillary files `.aux`, `.bbl` etc. when you change an encoding.   Old files with a previous chosen encoding will cause confusion.